# Terraform list of maps for IBM CAM

Tags: ibm-cloud, terraform, terraform-template-file

I am trying to create a IBM CAM template with a list of maps with the following code in the camvariables.json

```
{
  "name": "list_of_maps",
  "type": "list",
  "description": "list of maps test",
  "hidden": false,
  "label": "List of maps",
  "secured": false,
  "required": true,
  "immutable": false,
  "group_name": "virtualmachine",
  "default":
    [{
       "field1":"value1",
       "field2":"value14",
       "field3":"value15",
       "field4":"value16",
       "field5":"value17",
       "field6":"value13",
       "field7":"value18",
       "field8":"value1t",
       "field9":"value1u",
       "field10":"value1d",
       "field11":"value1sd",      
       "field12":"value2"
    }]
},
```

The output is.

[image: CAM template]

I changed the type from list to map where I get all the key value pairs and an add button which would only add a key value pair.

**What I am trying to achieve**

I have a group ABC with 5 variables in the CAM template. I want to make the group a list.

```
ABC_attr1
ABC_attr2
ABC_attr3
ABC_attr4
```

On the CAM template I want to be able to insert multiple values to the CAM template during the deployment.